# Как задать начальное значение для mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Помогите пожалуйста, есть див с id `<div id="map"></div>` и скрипт к этому id:

Подключенный скрипт:

```html
<script src=https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v4.0.2/mapbox-gl-directions.js></script>
```

Внутри данного скрипта есть переменная

```js
var initialState = {
  // Options set on initialization
  api: 'https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/',
  profile: 'mapbox/driving-traffic',
  alternatives: false,
  congestion: false,
  unit: 'imperial',
  flyTo: true,
  placeholderOrigin: '123',
  placeholderDestination: 'Choose destination',
  zoom: 16,
  language: 'en',
  compile: null,
  proximity: false,
  styles: [],
```

Как поменять

```
placeholderDestination: 'Choose destination',
```

на

```
placeholderDestination: 'last',
```

не изменяя подключаемый скрипт?

Comment: `initialState.placeholderDestination = 'last';` о_О

Comment: Эм.. Выделить текст и написать на его месте другой.

Comment: Было бы так все просто, это ссылка на скрипт

Comment: @GoldenBro, поправил вопрос - всё правильно понял?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да спасибо))